# MySQL Functions Didn't return any value

Tags: mysql, function

I trying to write MySql Function to return the count of child for one node and the I wrote this code

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `get_child_count`(`id` INT) RETURNS int(11)
READS SQL DATA
Begin
declare temp int(11);
SELECT count(*) into temp FROM tbl_photo_album where parent_id = id;
return temp;
End
```

and everytime I tried to run this function it come with nothing.

Comment: Have you tried executing the query outside the function to see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

Possible alternative: Instad of `select ... into...`, try this:

```
set temp = (select count(*) from tbl_photo_album where parent_id = id);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

```
 DELIMITER $$
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `get_child_count`(`id` INT) RETURNS int(11)
 READS SQL DATA
 Begin
 declare temp int(11);
 SELECT count(*) into temp FROM tbl_photo_album where parent_id = id;
 return temp;
 END$$
DELIMITER ;

select get_child_count(10); --  Pass Id for what you want result.
```